# How to implement muti-condition filter cleverly?

Tags: python

I need to find a way to make the part of search more cleverly and concise. If you have any idea to avoid too many if-elif I will be grateful(I don't mind if you use mysql or other database).Here is my code:

```
 if x==0 and y==0:
     query=db.session.filter(condition A, condition B)
 elif x==0 and y==1:
      query=db.session.filter(condition A, condition C)
 elif x==1 and y==0:
     ...
```

one more question: x  and y have default value -1 , if y==-1 the code may be like this :

```
lookup_table = {
  #x  y
  (0, 0): (condition A, condition B),
  (0, 1): (condition A, condition C),
  (0,-1): condition A     #the condition B should be omited 
   (-1,0): condition B    #the condition A should be omited 
  # ...
}
```

now arg1,*arg2=lookup_table[(x,y)] will be ok, but I think it is  not clean enough. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lookup table using a dictionary, and index it using a tuple of `x` and `y`:

```
# Create the lookup table
lookup_table = {
  #x  y
  (0, 0): (condition A, condition B),
  (0, 1): (condition A, condition C),
  # ...
}

# Find the values required for the (x, y) key
arg1, arg2 = lookup_table[(x, y)]

# Call the filter method
query = db.session.filter(arg1, arg2)
```

This looks quite clean, and also allows you to generate the lookup table itself programmatically if you need to.